# Button not visible in main activity

Tags: java, android

I have create three button in main activity. i used following code for button one

```
`btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
btn.setVisibility(GONE);
btn1.setVisibility(GONE);
btn2.setVisibility(GONE);
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment).addToBackStack(null.commit();`
```

the problem is that when i pressed back button than buttons not visible in main activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you press back button you return your activity back but you've already set your buttons' visibilities as Gone that's why you can't see those buttons. You have to handle back button and set buttons' visibilities as Visible again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn, btn1, btn2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btn.setVisibility(GONE);
                btn1.setVisibility(GONE);
                btn2.setVisibility(GONE);
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
                fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
    //Handle your Back Button with onKeyDown method.
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        //Check for if Back Button is pressed. If pressed do below:
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            onBackPressed(); //Return your activity back.
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  //Set your btn's visibility as Visible.
            btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Set your btn1's visibility as Visible.
            btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //Set your btn2's visibility as Visible.
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please guide me in proper way I am beginner.

Comment: I have code for fragment in java. now i want to used same code for activity not for fragment. basically i want convert that code for activity. code is below.   https://docs.google.com/document/d/16v65hcU7fXl7iF34ov9IMJH60iTMjn14TVAIV9ca3cg/edit

Comment: I suggest create new title about your new question and share your codes there and be more specific about your problem or request.

Comment: I already created new question but not received any answers.  Here is my question link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570891/i-want-covert-code-from-fragment-to-activity

Answer (score 1):

You have set their *visibility* to **GONE**, so if you want to have them again you should set their *visibility* to **VISIBLE**

Comment: when button one click open a fragment. after back pressed in fragment than button is not visible. actually i use fragments. ' onResume ' method is not working.

Comment: In logcat check which function is running, oncreate, onstart, onresume, etc. At that function make buttons visible @ravindra

Comment: oncreate function is running

Comment: OK, in oncreate set visibilities to VISIBLE @ravindra

Comment: understand my question please. i create 3 button in main activity when i click on button than open fragment.in fragment i don"t want show button that's why i made button visibility GONE. means if i click on button open a fragment and in fragment button don't visible but when i back press than in main activity all  button visible.

Comment: In the fragment make buttons GONE and in activity make them VISIBLE @ravindra

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213006/discussion-between-ravindra-and-mohammadmoeingolchin).

Comment: I have three buttons inside the main activity. When I click on any of the buttons, a new fragment opens. Visibility of the three buttons disappears as soon as I click. Clicking on the button opens the fragments. When I press back from fragment, all three buttons in the man activity are not visible. I want all three buttons to be visible when I come back to activity from fragments.

Comment: I answered you in chat @ravindra

Answer (score 1):

you have to use event bus. it's used for pass data from fragment to activity.

your fragment back press method, you have to pass boolean value on your first activity and get the boolean value in your activity. that time you have to visible your button.

this is link for event bus:= [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

Happy Coding

Comment: when button one click open a fragment. after back pressed in fragment than button is not  visible. actually i use fragments. ' onResume ' method is not working.

Comment: I have three buttons inside the main activity. When I click on any of the buttons, a new fragment opens. Visibility of the three buttons disappears as soon as I click. Clicking on the button opens the fragments. When I press back from fragment, all three buttons in the man activity are not visible. I want all three buttons to be visible when I come back to activity from fragments.